# how to check element visibility on facebook dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, dom

I'm trying to build chrome extenstion to monitor user feed on facebook, I'm using MutationObserver on the dom to observe - `role='feed'`, but i get data about posts the user cant see yet, I tried to check if the post element is visible at current time with html attributes of the element, but there isnt enough information for this. all attrubutes has same values for all elements. 
`offsetHeight =0`, `offsetParent= null`, all style info for `element =""`,
there is a way its possible to know if post is visible to user at this point of time?